# Codeigniter Pagination link is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink, controller, pagination

so many pagination question on stackoverflow, but i can't see it with codeigniter, so here it goes.

we need to look at these picture
[image]

and here

[image]

and here

[image]

i have ten record on the table, and the link is not working, here is the `controller/index`

```
$query = $this->m_kategorimaterial->get();  
    $config['base_url'] =  base_url().'index.php/c_kategorimaterial/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 5; 
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['rows'] = $query->result();
    $data['title'] = 'QB Kategori Material';
    $this->load->view('menu',$data);
    $this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial');
```

and here is the model

```
 $this->db->order_by('Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa','DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material');
    return $query;
```

why does the link is not working ? how do i resolve it ? Thank you stackoverflow

Comment: Can you please tell, what URL's are getting generated when you are on 1st, 2nd and 3rd page respectively.

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't understand what you mean, so i need to make another similiar page to show the 2nd, 3rd list and so on ?

Comment: No, I mean please share the full url, when page is first loaded, then when you click on second link and so on.

Comment: ahh wait, the pagination is disappear ! i try to make them displayed first\

Comment: As Rick Calder, said you need to pass offset and limit to model, to fetch only five records from given offset

Comment: i don't understand about the offset here http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/queries-limit.html when i change the model into `$query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material',3,0);` and the controller into `$config['per_page'] = 1` the pagination is displayed, and still the link is not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18578/discussion-between-kalpesh-patel-and-cignitor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you calling the offset in the data gathering query? You need to provide an offset to the query so it knows which records to get.

You'll also have to change the total_rows to a second query that queries the entire table for total records since your new query only returns enough records for one page.

Model:

```
$this->db->order_by('Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa','DESC');
$query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material', $limit, $offset);
return $query;

function getRecordCount() {

$query=$this->db->get('ms_kategori_material');
$result = $query->num_rows();
return $result;
}
```

Controller:

```
$config['base_url'] =  base_url().'index.php/c_kategorimaterial/index/';
$config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = 5; 
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$query = $this->m_kategorimaterial->get($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
$data['rows'] = $this->m_kategorimaterial->getRecordCount();
$data['title'] = 'QB Kategori Material';
$this->load->view('menu',$data);
$this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial');
```

Seems you could use a small explanation of what's happening here. To do pagination CI (or any application) needs at minimum 3 variables.

limit - how many records per page should I show, and consequently how many records does my query return.

offset - Where does the query start asking for records, with CI this is where the uri segment comes in, it's controlled partially by the limit so if you have 8 as a limit (per_page) each query increments the offset by 8. So page 1 queries the database for the first 8 records starting at the beginning, page two the first 8 records starting at record 9 and so on.

Total records - This is the total matching records for the query in the entire table(s). This is how the application determines how many pages there are in total and whether a second page is required at all. This query has no limit or offset because you want all the matching records and not a partial return.

The actual pagination of the data is carried out by the database query. CI just tells the database which records it needs.

Hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: then i change the model into `$query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material',5,0);` still no pagination is displayed *i am using your controller*

Comment: can you please give me an example due to pagination link ? i have ten records on database, i want to make it 5 record per page, so pagination will show 1st and 2nd page. the 1st will show from `kkmj010` to `kkmj006` and the 2nd page will show from `kkmj005` to `kkmj001`

Comment: Edited answer to show you the record count, that is assuming your model is called m_kategorimaterial it returns the full records, the other query returns the data 5 at a time, CI does the rest for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
```

Here is the full info you need > http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: when i change the model into `$query = $this->db->get('ms_kategori_material',2);` and i change the controller into `$config['per_page'] = 5; ` the pagination is not showing

Comment: Because you're setting the total rows to the query, as I said you need a second query to get the total rows. Try manually setting the total rows to 10

Comment: Edited answer to explain what is going on here, hopefully that helps you understand the bits you're missing.